# Create a dart udp or tcp server inside a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, server, udp, multiplayer

I'm making a multiplayer game in flutter and I wanted to know if it was possible to create a server in a flutter app.

Here is what I want to do :
You'll have a home page where you can choose between host a game and join a game. If you choose to host a game, it create a server and shows your IP adress. 
If you choose to join a game, you can enter an IP adress and join the game that the other has create.

I'm open to any other solutions to connect two or more phones without extern server. It can be bluetooth connexion, wifi connextion or anything. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Tale a look at this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/udp

Comment: Thanks !!! And is there any solution with TCP Server ?

Comment: Hey Simon, did you come to any nice solution on this?

Comment: @jlee7 nope  i didn't

Comment: I think I will give sockets a try: https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-sockets-in-dart-15b443007bc9

Comment: Yeah, it might be a good idea, or create an external server...